# Sets meeting and avoiding computable sets

Tags: computability-theory

Call a set $X$ *hesive* if for every infinite computable set $C$, both $C \cap X$ and $C \setminus X$ are infinite.

It's not hard to see that every hyperimmune degree computes a hesive set, but this isn't a characterization, since also any random set is hesive (in fact, Church stochasticity suffices).

Does every noncomputable degree compute a hesive set?

Comment: Interesting question +1.  Your title refers to "meeting and avoid computable sets", but the property is about computable sets meeting and avoiding $X$.

Comment: Do you know what happens with a Sacks-generic real?

Comment: A Sacks-generic real won't itself be hesive, but it might compute one.  I'll think on that a bit.

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps a fusion argument would enable you to prove it also couldn't compute one. Only countably many programs, and the fusion argument can handle them one at a time.

Comment: "A set"... you mean, a subset of the set of integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is hesive iff $X$ is bi-immune.

Jockusch showed that a Sacks generic has bi-immune-free degree.

*Jockusch, C. G. Jr.*, [**The degrees of bi-immune sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/malq.19690150707), Z. Math. Logik Grundlagen Math. 15, 135-140 (1969). [ZBL0184.02002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0184.02002).

So no, not every noncomputable degree contains a hesive set.

Comment: Does he use a fusion argument?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I don't think he advertised it as such, but maybe.

Comment: With a Sack real, I would think he did, since that is the main thing to do with Sacks reals and the trees approximating them.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I think Spector constructed a minimal Turing degree using "uniform" trees and those don't suffice to force bi-immunity. Can you do fusion arguments with those trees?

Comment: Fusion is the process when you have a sequence of trees, such that they are refining each other as you go along, but after stage $n$ the first $n$ splitting levels are preserved (so you have to prune quickly enough). In this case, the fusion of the trees is the limit tree. I'm not sure what notion of "uniform" you are using, but there are various notions of spliting requirements etc., and most of the ones I know do implement a version of fusion. Fusion is a substitue for countable closure---the forcing isn't closed, but with fusion, you can nevertheless often get by.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Thanks, Richard Shore told me about that at some point but a reminder was helpful.

Comment: Ah, of course.  Very nice.